# Error while reading file. Maximum call stack size exceeded, while trying to create item with mongoose in stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-streams

i'm trying to write to DB, while reading from big CSV file in stream, but all i get is 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error. And always after 12969 row. If i don't save to DB, everything ok. My code example:

```
const s = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../data.csv'))
.pipe(csv.parse({delimiter: ';', columns: true }))
.pipe(es.mapSync(line => {
  s.pause();

  if(validate(line)){
    const newStation = new Station({
      ...line
    });

    newStation
      .save()
      .then((item) => {
        overlaps++;
        s.resume();
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
        s.resume();
        throw err;
      });
  }else{
    s.resume();
  }
}))
.on('error', function(err){
  res.end(`Reading error: ${err.message}`);
  console.log('Error while reading file.', err.message);
})
.on('end', function(){
  res.end(`Done reading, items: ${overlaps}`);
  console.log(`Done reading items`)
});
```

Comment: If i remove s.pause() and s.resume(), everything works fine. Can anybody explain, what going on?

Comment: I think that trouble is in es.mapSync. What does it do?

Comment: You were right, change mapSync to es.map with callback helps. I'm not really good with streams, i take es.mapSync from example somewhere on SO, thats some kind of stream helpers, https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream